# Any way to include subproject buildSrc into root project's buildSrc class path?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

In attempting to port a somewhat complicated build setup with Gradle (migrating from ancient Gradle versions) and wanting to use Kotlin-DSL, I've run into the issue of being unable to "include"/"compile"/"depend on" the subproject's buildSrc class path.

The projects in reference:

- [SpongeAPI](https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeAPI)
- [SpongeCommon](https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeCommon)
- [SpongeForge](https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeForge/)

So far I've already migrated virtually all of SpongeAPI with the following pr:

https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeAPI/pull/1980/files

The way the file structure is set up is as follows:

```
SpongeForge (root project)
| - SpongeCommon
|    | - SpongeAPI
|    |   | - build.gradle
|    |   | - gralde/
|    |   |    | - sponge.gradle
|    |   |    | - deploy.gradle
|    | - Gradle/
|    |   | - Minecraft.gradle (Defines some gradle plugin to set up Minecraft dependencies)
|    |   | - implementation.gradle (sets up SpongeForge/SpongeVanilla to depend on common)
|    | - build.gradle
| - build.gradle
```

With the SpongeAPI setup with Kotlin-DSL, I've managed to extract a lot of things into a gradle plugin, but with various string dependencies defined by constants (like dependency versions, groups, etc.)

The issue I have is that when I started working on migrating SpongeCommon, adding a buildSrc to SpongeCommon will result in SpongeAPI's buildSrc plugin to fail to compile or SpongeAPI's build script to fail to compile because the SpongeAPI/buildSrc is no longer in it's class path.

One really silly way I've thought of resolving this was to set up a depends on task to copy the contents of SpongeAPI/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin to SpongeCommon's/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin, but then I run into the issue of a) duplicative files, b) attempting to use the IDE for SpongeAPI's buildSrc files will not work because the class path for that buildSrc isn't set up.

So, I'm curious, if anyone has gotten around this sort of issue, let me know what your thoughts are.

Comment: I have this same problem in gradle project, where I want to add a buildSrc dependency in a sub module to root dependency

Comment: Still, so far, there's no real solution except to have a composite build that contains the buildSrc plugins for all modules. I've yet to actually migrate the projects because of these limitations. I submitted an issue [to kotlin-dsl](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1362#issuecomment-472755481) but it's been closed and no responses about whether such a feature is potentially valid or not...